# Android - Node.getNodeValue() truncating when there is &apos;

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I'm parsing some XML with `XPath`.

The XML code follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <teldir>
    <contact>
      <nameDept>D&apos;ADAMO, Piergiorgio</nameDept>
    </contact>
  </teldir> 
</response>
```

Using the expression `/response/teldir/contact/nameDept/text()` I put the result in a Java String with `Node.getNodeValue()`.

This string is shown in a `ListView` using a custom but simple layout for each item.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/contact_name_dept" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
/>
```

I have a unit test asserting the string is `"D'ADAMO, Piergiorgio"`.

The problem is that *only* when the code runs in the emulator the item in the `ListView` shows `"D'"`.

It seems that `Node.getNodeValue()` is truncating the string when the apostrophe occurs.

Maybe the `Node` DOM implementation in Android has issues?

Comment: You shouldn't have to escape the text... Try logging the string before assigning it to the textview to make sure it actually contains what you think it contains.

Comment: @Yoni Very good hint! It seems that _only_ when the code runs inside the emulator (unit test is OK) `Node.getNodeValue()` truncates after the apostrophe. Issue with Android DOM implementation?

Comment: Possibly. I think most of the Android development effort relating to XML parsing wen into XmlPullParser; DOM/XPath is pretty slow on mobile devices.

Comment: Also, this is one reason why I personally run my unit tests with the Android JUnit test runner; while most things work the way you'd expect in the normal JVM, I wouldn't bet my release on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath specification requires that adjacent text nodes are concatenated, so using /text() should never give you half a text node. Unfortunately there are some careless implementations around, and if they run on a DOM that has multiple adjacent text nodes (as can often happen when entities are involved) they don't go to the trouble of merging them. It's a non-conformance and you should complain about it, but you'll be lucky to get it fixed. Meanwhile, try to get out of the habit of using /text() in your XPath expressions - it's nearly always bad practice. Instead, get the string value of the containing element using `string(/response/teldir/contact/nameDept)`. It's very unlikely that any XPath implementation will get that one wrong (I hope!).

Comment: Very very great answer! If I could give you +100 I'd give it to you! Using `string()` solved my problems!